# Reducer React Typescript Error: No overload matches this call when use reducer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

It's okay if I return state, but why do I get error??
I'm currently reaching out for help as typescript gave me the following error that I cannot just make sense of it when trying to write a useReducer.

This is my Error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suQ19.png)

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 5, '(reducer: ReducerWithoutAction, initializerArg: any, initializer?: undefined): [any, DispatchWithoutAction]', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(state: IMeeting[], action: ReducerAction) => (number | IMeeting)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReducerWithoutAction'.
> Overload 2 of 5, '(reducer: (state: IMeeting[], action: ReducerAction) => (number | IMeeting)[], initialState: never, initializer?: undefined): [never, Dispatch]', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'IMeeting[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2769)

```
const initListMeeting: IMeeting[] = meetingData;

type ReducerAction = {
  type: REDUCER_ACTIONS;
  payload: IMeeting | number;
};

type MeetingsContext = {
  children: ReactElement | ReactElement[];
};

export type ListMeetingContextType = {
  listMeeting: IMeeting[];
  dispatch: Dispatch<ReducerAction>;
};

const reducer = (state: IMeeting[], action: ReducerAction) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REDUCER_ACTIONS.ADD_MEETING:
      return [...state, action.payload];
    case REDUCER_ACTIONS.REMOVE_MEETING:
      return [...state].filter((meeting) => meeting.id !== action.payload);
    case REDUCER_ACTIONS.UPDATE_MEETING:
      return state.map((meeting) =>
        meeting.id === (action.payload as IMeeting).id
          ? (action.payload)
          : meeting,
      );
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const ListMeetingContext = createContext<ListMeetingContextType>({
  listMeeting: meetingData,
  dispatch: () => null,
});

export const StateProvider = ({ children }: MeetingsContext): JSX.Element => {
  const [listMeeting, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initListMeeting);

  return (
    <ListMeetingContext.Provider value={{ listMeeting, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </ListMeetingContext.Provider>
  );
```

[my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suQ19.png)

Comment: I'm new to redux, but did you intend to have your state as Array and not object?

Comment: this is not redux reducer, it is react reducer

Answer (score 0):

Your reducer should always return a state which its type is `IMeeting[]` but if you check your reducer return type you will see it is `(IMeeting | number)[]`.

To fix this you need either cast the type of payload to IMeeting when you know it does have this type like this:

```js
...
        return [...state, action.payload as IMeeting];
...
            ? (action.payload as IMeeting)
```

Or replace your `ReducerAction` by a disjunctive union type like this :

```js
  type ReducerAction = {
    type: REDUCER_ACTIONS.ADD_MEETING | REDUCER_ACTIONS.UPDATE_MEETING;
    payload: IMeeting;
  } | {
    type: REDUCER_ACTIONS.REMOVE_MEETING;
    payload: number;
  };
```

Comment: is there any solution without having to cast the type? because there is a case of passing the payload as id:number

Comment: yes the second one, you don't need to make a cast at all

Comment: I had a type, the second payload in the union type is a number, I've updated the answer